How to sort out this logical mess with my javascript?
I have a Google Sheet and I'm trying to output a date or string depending on three dates and three booleans which represent a task as complete.
I've been writing a custom function to do this but I can't get the logic to work out, I've been working on it for days now.
In my sheet, I have an initial date. The three dates the tasks are due are calculated in columns D, F and H. Then there are three 'done' booleans that represent whether a task has been completed.
I want this to reduce down to a single output where a date is given for the 'next date a task is due', or if the last task is done, then mark it as 'DELETE'. The complicated part comes when a later task takes priority over a task not completed on an earlier date.
But the logic is too hard. I can't seem to break it down to a way I can solve how to do it.
In my sheet I have put the expected outputs for each case. (I'm aware I haven't even sampled all 64 cases, but I daren't mess with too much at this point).
So essentially, I need a function to take the dates and dones and then get the result.
function myFunction(date1,date2,date3,done1,done2,done3) {
  
  var TODAY = new Date();

  DATES = [date1,date2,date3]

  var wait = []

  for (var k of [date1,date2,date3]){
    if (k > TODAY){
      wait.push(1)
    }else{
      wait.push(0)
    }
  }

  var done = []

   for (var k of [done1,done2,done3]){
    if (k){
      done.push(1)
    }else{
      done.push(0)
    }
  }

  var omega = []
  for (var i = 0; i < wait.length; i++) {
    omega.push(done[i] | wait[i])
  }               

As you can see, my last attempt included doing an OR function on then and taking the rightmost zeros, but ignore that because it doesn't work.
Anyone know how I should try this in a way that works?

It would be helpful if you added examples of expected inputs and outputs to your question.

@MattMorgan The expected inputs and outputs are in the Google Sheet.

The best practice on Stack Overflow is for the questions to stand on their own, and include the minimal code and data needed to reproduce the issue being asked about.  Links to external resources can get stale and break, making the question/answer less useful for future readers.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (see "Help others reproduce the problem")

Try this adapted version of @mplungjan 's code
I swapped in an array map that establishes the priority of completed tasks and closes out incomplete precursor tasks.
function myFunction(date1, date2, date3, done1, done2, done3) {
  const today = new Date();
  const dates = [new Date(date1), new Date(date2), new Date(date3)];
  var dones = [done1, done2, done3];

  // Completes earlier tasks if subsequent tasks are completed
  var dones = dones.map((val,index) => { if(dones.lastIndexOf('x')>=index ) {return 'x'}});

  // Filter for dates that are not done
  const futureDates = dates.filter((date,index) => !dones[index]);

  // Find the earliest date from the filtered future dates
  const nextDueDate = futureDates.reduce((earliest, date) => {
    return date < earliest ? date : earliest;
  }, new Date('2999-12-31')); // initial date far in the future

  // If the nextDueDate year is still in the far future then all tasks are done (on no dates)
  return (nextDueDate.getFullYear() === 2999) ? 'DELETE' : nextDueDate.toLocaleDateString(); // Returns the next due date in a readable format
}


Thanks, but it's still not working correctly. The Google Sheet shows what outputs I'm expecting for each permutation of the inputs. So myFunction(02-June-2024, 03-June-2024, 04-June-2024, 0, 0, 0) = 02-June-2024 because it's the earliest date not done. But instead @mplungjan's code outputs 'DELETE' as does yours.

Ignore me. I'm not sure I saved it after pasting in your code, haha. Now it seems to be working differently. But there's still a few cases where it's not working correctly. `myFunction(12-June, 13-June, 14-June,0,1,0) = 14-June because in this case the fact 13 June is done overrides that fact an earlier date isn't done.

Ohhh, it's chaining priority, let me adjust the source and I'll let you know when it's ready.

There's probably a cleaner way to accomplish this, but this works :)
